# popup a html file on click

Tags: html, popup

I am trying to open a html page when clicking on a link as pop-up
I am a layman in html. I tried to read many sources with the method like lightbox, jquery etc..which I am not at all familiar with.

Currently, I have the page(poem.html), which goes to 2nd page (jbn.html). But I want it to be popped up.

For html5, I found dialogue is the standard method, but the example I found does not include external html file. I have to write everything inside the dialogue tag. But, for my purpose, it would be better if I can popup an external file.
The minimal example for this is:

**poem.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <head>
        <title>Bangla Kobita</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="container">
          <div id="header">
          <div id="content">
           <h3>XYZ</h3>
            <ol>
               <li><a href="jbn.html">abc</a></li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**jbn.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Bangla Kobita</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="content">
      <h2>jbn</h2>
      <h3>xyz</h3> 
     some text here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Being a novice, I have not managed to open the html file as popup.

I have, after days of hard work, manged to open a image file as popup with:

```
      <div class="lb-overlay" id="jbn">
    <img src="kobita/jbn.png" alt="jbn" class="poems"/>
    <a href="poem.html" class="lb-close">Close</a>
      </div>
```

where lb-* is defined in a css. 
But I cant open a html file.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="jbn.html" target="popup" onclick="window.open('jbn.html','jbnWindow','width=600,height=400')">abc</a>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply...but isn't it just a popup, not lightbox?

Comment: That's correct. Do you want a lightbox instead? I was under the impression that you just wanted a link that created a popup.

Comment: yes...actually I am too new to learn the proper terms. But I have managed to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden">
     <div data-role="popup" id="externalpage">
         <iframe src="jbn.html" 
                 width="500" 
                 height="500" 
                 seamless>
          </iframe>
     </div>
</div>    
<!-- Poem.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <head>
        <title>Bangla Kobita</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="container">
          <div id="header">
          <div id="content">
           <h3>XYZ</h3>
            <ol>
               <li><a data-rel="popup"  data-role="button" href="#externalpage">abc</a></li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

You can achieve that using jQuery mobile...but when u click outside the pop up it will get killed..Hope this could help you

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="#" onClick="MyWindow=window.open('jbn.html','MyWindow','width=600,height=300'); return false;">Open Jbn</a>
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.